# Have we ever seen a Stargate in the Ori galaxy or isn't there one at all?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

I have recently read the article about the [Stargates](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate) and I have been comparing the designs in each galaxy. I tried to recall any Stargate from the Ori/Alteran home galaxy for comparison, but I couldn't.

We know that the inventor of the Stargate, [Amelius](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Amelius), had left the Ori galaxy with other Alterans before he created it (all we see are the sketches/designs made on paper). Therefore, either the Ori do not have the knowledge how to create them, or they have invented them on their own. They surely have the understanding of the technology - we see them using the Milky Way stargates and they have constructed the Supergate.

We know that the Priors arrive in the Milky Way galaxy through Stargate, so we **assume** that there is another one on the other end. But do we ever see one? There might be a local Stargate network in the Ori galaxy or maybe they have just tapped into the Milky Way network with a different device?

The Stargate wikia [lists a few](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_Network) in the Alteran galaxy, but does not have any images for them.

Comment: Ori built ship gates at one point, so they at least understand the gate technology.

Comment: Surely they understand the technology - they have built the Supergate and made the Priors arrive through the Milky Way stargates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## We never see them, but they do exist and we know they do not look like the ones in *Stargate Universe*

Executive producer Joseph Mallozi answered a question in his [July 19, 2010](https://josephmallozzi.com/2010/07/19/july-19-2010-masked-hits-the-streets-last-days-of-atlantis-mailbag/) mailbag that indicated that the Ori did have Stargates, and that they were not like the ones seen in *Stargate Universe*.

> Gabriele writes: “4. We know that in the Ori galaxy there are gates. The Priors used them to come through the Milky Way gates and probably the people in that galaxy use them to get to other planets. Is it possible that the seeder ships reached the Ori-Ancient home galaxy long ago and seeded the Destiny gates on those planets? So, is it possible that the gates in the Ori galaxy are of the same model as the gates that we see in “Stargate Universe”?”
>
> Answer: I don’t believe they were.

If the fan was incorrect about the presence of Stargates in the Ori galaxy, I expect that Mallozi would have taken the time to correct them. His answer seems to confirm that they do indeed exist there.

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR**

- We do not know for sure.
- Obviously they know how...
- The Ori only provided the information when it was needed.

We never learned if gate travel was piece of the Ori galaxy's culture. There are only two Ori planets we ever see: Celestis and Ver Isca.

Celestis is the initial planet we see that Daniel and Vala use the communication stones to visit. We only ever see a small town square and the City of Celestis (where the Ori wall of fire was), but we never see a stargate at either location.

Ver Isca is the planet that Vala was transported to after sacrificing herself by taking the last place in the supergate chain. This is the planet where she met Tomin. We see more of this planet than the first, but still no stargates.

What we do know is that when the Ori decide to invade we begin to see armor, weapons, ships, and gates all being constructed. Prior to this it does not appear there was any, nor any indication of anything else beyond a "medieval" level of society.

This would make it seem the Ori only provided the know how to construct such things when it became necessary (and likely without explanation) in an attempt to keep the populace subservient and ignorant; the same SOP that the Goa'uld followed. Obviously you appear more godlike and powerful the more ignorant your servants are and the Ori only need the faith of their servants, not their intelligence.

Off those two points we can make an intelligent guess that either the gates existed (and likely only the priors had access to them) or that the Ori simply built one after discovering the Milky Way exists so they could send an initial emissary to our galaxy... my money is on the later.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. After reading this the other day I decided to make a video about it to answer your question. Well most of it.